# Core demagnetisation - What is the condition?

Tags: transformer, dc-dc-converter, magnetics, forward

Consider forward converter topology.
What is necessary for core to be successfully demagnetised? Does the magnetising current has to reach absolute zero amps, or even little negative is advantage?
How about voltage across windings? Seems the voltage reaching 0V naturally is sufficient, no need to goes negative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is necessary for core to be successfully demagnetised?*

In simple terms, the **average** voltage across the driven winding has to be zero volts else the current will continue rising until the core saturates.

> *Seems the voltage reaching 0V naturally is sufficient, no need to goes
> negative.*

Consider a voltage (blue) applied across a 5 henry inductor and, look at the current in red: -

[image]

When the positive voltage pulse drops to 0 volts (after 3 seconds), the current remains at 6 amps then, when the next voltage pulse arrives, current begins ramping-up from 6 amps. I think you can see that you need a negative voltage to de-flux the core and prevent an ever-increasing flux in a positive direction.

So, if the negative voltage was 4.2857 volts you would get this: -

[image]

Current has returned to zero when the next positive pulse arrives and, flux doesn't walk-upwards towards core saturation. This is because the average voltage is precisely zero.

> *Does the magnetising current has to reach absolute zero amps, or even
> little negative is advantage?*

In a practical forward converter demagnetization is typically applied via a 3rd winding connected via a diode to the power rails. This ensures that demagnetization takes place before the next switching cycle begins. Once the magnetic energy from the core has been recycled to the power rail, the current stops at zero amps due to the diode.

Comment: Ok. But positive voltage causes magnetisation + secondary current. On other hand the negative voltage just demagnetisation only. Then how the “voltage average condition”you mention can be valid?

Comment: Secondary current is irrelevant @MichalPodmanický because when the secondary load takes current from the secondary, an equivalent ampere-turn current enters the primary and, both these produce zero net flux hence, secondary current is irrelevant. This then allows you to think of the primary like an inductor so, the analysis and solution then reduces to "the average voltage across an inductor must be zero" <-- does this make any more sense?

Comment: So, @MichalPodmanický the positive voltages on the primary must be balanced by the negative voltages on the primary (aka average of zero).

Comment: Thx for simulation. It makes sense. Then it’d mean if transformer is nor driven with perfect symmetry the core end up saturated in one or another direction. Is there some reason it avoids this?

Comment: @MichalPodmanický the basic forward converter allows the core flux to return to zero by using a diode and a third winding. This in effect is the same as ensuring that the primary applied voltage averages at zero. The two switch forward converter uses diodes and an extra MOSFET to do the same thing. You can also use a capacitor and diode to demagnetize the core.

Comment: It's the same problem any transformer has to face; even AC to AC voltage transformers. If the AC input voltage does not have an average value of zero volts then, the only thing that prevents massive saturation is the winding resistance.

Answer (score 1):

The positive volt-second area must be equal to the negative volt-second area. The current does not necessarily need to go negative to provide this.

There may also be another winding that provides the demagnetizing flux such as in a forward converter.